# How can I rewrite a trace of a matrix product to a product of matrices?

Tags: matrices, trace

Is there any way to transform $C=\mathrm{Tr}\left(AX\right)$ to $C=KX$ or $C=KXM$, $K$ and $M$ can be some arbitrary matrices? I mean I want to get rid of the trace operator and keep the matrix $X$.

Comment: No, not really. Can you be more specific about why you want such an expression?

Comment: What is $X$?  ...

Comment: sorry X is a matrix too, which is inside the trace operator, I have just edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible if $A$ is a rank 1 matrix. In that case we can write $A=uv^T$, where $u$ and $v$ are column vectors.

$$
\mathrm{Tr}(AX)=\mathrm{Tr}(uv^TX)=\mathrm{Tr}(v^TXu)=v^TXu
$$

This is in fact only possible if $A$ is rank 1. After all, the trace operator maps onto a scalar, so the only way the expression $\mathrm{Tr}\left(AX\right) = KXM$ makes any sense is if $K$ is a $1 \times n$  and $M$ is $n \times 1$ (and $X$ is $n \times n$).

However, general matrices can be expressed it a sum of rank-1 matrices, so sometimes it may be helpful to write this:

$$
A = \sum_{i=1}^k u_i v_i^T \ \Leftrightarrow \ \mathrm{Tr}(AX)=\sum_{i=1}^k v_i^TXu_i, \ \forall X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a commutative ring, $n,m\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, $A=\left(a_{ij}\right)\in\mathrm{M}_{nm}\left(\mathbb{K}\right)$ and $B=\left(b_{ij}\right)\in\mathrm{M}_{mn}\left(\mathbb{K}\right)$ (as the trace is defined for square matrices, the size of $A$ and $B$ must agree).
We have
$$\left(AB\right)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{m}a_{ik}b_{kj}\quad\quad\quad 1\leq i,j\leq n$$
and then
$$\mathrm{Tr}\left(AB\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{ij}b_{ji}.$$
You can get this element of $\mathbb{K}$ with the matrix product $XY$, where
$$X=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1m} & a_{21} & \cdots & a_{2m} & \cdots & a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nm}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$Y=
\begin{pmatrix}b_{11} & b_{21} & \cdots & b_{m1} & b_{12} & \cdots & b_{1n} & \cdots & b_{1n} & \cdots & b_{mn}\end{pmatrix}^{T}.$$
Not sure if it answers the question.

**EDIT :**

For example, for two $2\times 2$ matrices, we have
$$\mathrm{{Tr}}\left(\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12}\\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{pmatrix}\right)=\mathrm{{Tr}}\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21} & a_{11}b_{12}+a_{12}b_{22}\\
a_{21}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{21} & a_{21}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$=a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21}+a_{21}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{21} & a_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b_{11}\\
b_{21}\\
b_{12}\\
b_{22}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

But the original question has been edited, so I'm not sure that this is an answer anymore.

Comment: Could you do a concrete example (just small 2x2 matrices)? I have trouble seeing it.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I have edited my post.